# melting data.table seems to crash RStudio?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

After a bit of googling and stalking stackoverflow, I think I may have stumbled onto a bug with the `reshape2` package (or `data.table`, I'm not sure). Specifically, I am unable to melt a particular `data.table` of mine.

Here's a reproducible example (you can find a copy of that particular .Rdata file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebhfyq12dwmmnrr/mpi_cv_vanilla_random_gov_17h55--100_class_widths.Rdata)):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

load("mpi_cv_vanilla_random_gov_17h55--100_class_widths.Rdata")

melt(par.grid.results)
```

Before I run `melt`, my `usessionInfo` is as follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
[4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.2.2    ggplot2_0.9.3.1   data.table_1.8.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.4       grid_3.0.2        
[5] gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-29        munsell_0.4.2     
[9] plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 scales_0.2.3      
[13] stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.2
```

And once I run `melt(par.grid.results)`, RStudio throws up the picture of the bomb with dialogue:

"R Session Aborted \nR encountered a fatal error \nThe session was terminated".

If anyone has any ideas as to what's going on, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Running this inside the terminal, I get the following error (segfault):

```
> melt(par.grid.results)
Using  as id variables

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: unlist(unname(data[var$measure]))
2: melt.data.frame(par.grid.results)
3: melt(par.grid.results)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Comment: Seems like your `.Rdata` file has an issue. Doing `dput(data.frame(.))` and then copy/paste'ng to another variable, converting it to a `data.table` and saving and loading it doesn't give me this error.

Comment: I don't really follow the whole `dput(...)` business. Can you elaborate (sorry, I'm a `data.table` newbie!)?

Comment: @StevieP `dput()` dumps the data into text format, which you can them paste back into R to recreate your data "from scratch." So if you have an error in your `.Rdata`, this might drop the error while saving the data.