# melt.data.table gives incorrect error report

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

`melt.data.table` gives incorrect error message when the user supplies a non-existent field in `id.vars`. It seems it gets the name of the missing field from `measure.vars` instead:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

x=data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2),phase=c('a','b','a','b'), metric=c(1,2,3,4))
melt(x,id.vars=c("id","phase"), measure.vars = c("non-existent-field"))
```

The error message given is:

```
Error in melt.data.table(x, id.vars = c("id", "phase"), measure.vars = c("non-existent-    field")) : 
  Column 'id' not found in 'data'
```

Follows R session info:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=ro_RO.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=ro_RO.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=ro_RO.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=ro_RO.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4     data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.1   stringr_0.6.2
```

I will file a bug but I am writing here so that other people can find this information. I lost some time trying to figure out what was happening... :-)

Comment: Thanks. It'd be nice if you could test on the development version before filing / posting inconsistencies/bug reports. This seems to give the right error message, following [this recent fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24327529/559784) on 1.9.3... Could you please verify?

Comment: I see you've filed [#714](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/714) as well, which I've closed now. I think this post is unnecessary.

Comment: @Arun ok, no more posts. Unfortunately I cannot test on the development version. I use data.table in a production environment and I have no bandwidth for it... Anyway, if it is solved, it's solved! :-)

Comment: @vsalmendra, I see. Then I guess there's no other way out. You could post here on SO or directly on the data.table mailing list, which ever you prefer.